# Autofac instance per lifetime scope only on child scope, not on root

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm using autofac in my application and struggling to get this situation working.

I registered my type as a PerLifetimeScope, but this rule apply to the root container too.

I have an instance that should be shared only for requests done within a child LifetimeScope, but should always returns a new instance for requests done direct to the root container.

---

**To better describe:**

I have an mobile app that uses autofac to resolve dependencies.

I build one global container for the application. When the user navigates to a new page, I open a new scope from the container for this page.

The page could access an internal sqlite database using EntityFrameworkCore. The instance of the DbContext used to access the database should be the same for all dependencies in the page's scope.

I also have a ConfigurationsService class that I use like a dictionary (key/value) but stored in the database too.
This class should perform updates in the database outside of any scope from pages, not interacting with other changes made from the page.

When a single configuration is changed, it requests an instance of the DbContext, make the changes, and dispose the instance.

The problem here is that when the ConfigurationService requests the DbContext instance from the container (not scope), the DbContext will now be a shared instance, and the connection will stay alive until the container is disposed.

I could open an scope for this, but it leaves the control of the scope lifetime for every class that fall in the same situation.

UPDATE 1:

The next code represents really well the dependency hierarchy and the situation I described above.

```
// CLASSES
public class Context
{
}

public class Repository
{
    public Repository(Context context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public Context Context { get; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(Repository repository1, Repository repository2)
    {
        Repository1 = repository1;
        Repository2 = repository2;
    }

    public Repository Repository1 { get; }
    public Repository Repository2 { get; }
}

// SAMPLE
var repository1 = container.Resolve<Repository>();
var repository2 = container.Resolve<Repository>();
var viewModel = container.Resolve<ViewModel>();
```

1. The Context reference from repository1 and repository2 variables should be different instances.
2. The Context reference from viewModel.Repository1 and viewModel.Repository2 should be the same instance.

ViewModel is one of many classes that could have a dependency hierarchy like that.

The way I could get it to work for my situation was creating a service that manages the instances as singletons only within a scope that is not root.

```
// CLASSES
public class ScopeSingletons
{
    private readonly List<object> _instances = new List<object>();

    public T Get<T>(Func<T> factory)
    {
        var instance = _instances.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault();

        if (instance == null)
            _instances.Add(instance = factory());

        return instance;
    }
}

// SAMPLE
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ScopeSingletons>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ViewModel>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<Repository>().AsSelf();
builder.Register<Context>(c =>
{
    if (Equals((c as IInstanceLookup)?.ActivationScope.Tag, "root"))
        return new Context();

    return c.Resolve<ScopeSingletons>().Get(() => new Context());
});

var container = builder.Build();
var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();

var repository1 = container.Resolve<Repository>();
var repository2 = container.Resolve<Repository>();
var viewModel = scope.Resolve<ViewModel>();
```

In this case, everthing will work as I need. Context resolutions will be unique for every request within the root scope and shared within a child scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is... sort of a complicated thing and somewhat implies there may be some design issues. From my own experience, whenever I find I want to do X *except this one weird case where I want Y* it means I designed something wrong.

But let's say it's what you need.

From the "requirements" it sounds like the `ConfigurationServices` usage...

- Needs to control the creation and disposal of its own `DbContext` instances
- Is generally a singleton or otherwise lives at the root container level because it's used outside the context of your scope creation mechanism.
- If resolved inside a "page" it doesn't have to "share" the `DbContext` with the page. (It *could* but it doesn't *have to*.)

[**Sounds like a prime use case for the `Owned<T>` relationship.**](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html)

I'd set it up so...

- `ConfigurationServices` is a stateless singleton.
- When a context is needed in `ConfigurationServices` it handles the resolution, execution, and cleanup on the context.

It'd look something like this:

```
public class ConfigurationServices
{
  Func<Owned<DbContext>> _contextFactory;
  public ConfigurationServices(Func<Owned<DbContext>> contextFactory)
  {
    this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
  }

  public void DoWork()
  {
    using(var context = this._contextFactory().Value)
    {
      context.DoSomethingInDatabase();
    }
  }
}
```

The `Func<T>` relationship handles resolving - on the fly - a brand new instance of `Owned<T>`. The `Owned<T>` part means the container *won't* hold a reference to it in disposal and instead will let *you* control disposal.

Given `ConfigurationServices` would be a stateless singleton in this case, you could just register it like that.

```
builder.RegisterType<ConfigurationServices>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

Regardless of where it gets resolved, it'll come from the root container scope (all singletons do) which means the `Func<Owned<DbContext>>` will also come from there... but since you're using `Owned<T>` you won't have the inadvertent memory leak. The container won't hold the references for disposal.

Comment: I tried using Owned relationship but struggled to register the types so it could work with my dependency hierarchy.

I updated the question with a sample code.
I think that my situation is a lot like the InstancePerRequest configuration for a MVC Application.